# BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

Bug when first trying to run a brand new React Native application.

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

I encountered this error when I first installed the latest version of Java

> java 19.0.1

and creating a React Native application that auto generated with

> react-native dependency v0.70.6

Answer (score 51, accepted):

SOLUTION:

This is a dependency issue and we need the latest version of Gradle to support Java 19.

In your React Native application folder, nav to `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Find the `distributionUrl` variable and change the end path to `gradle-7.6-all.zip`

Comment: Save solution and path to gradle file when the problem is for an Android native app.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, can you help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76405709/react-native-v0-71-8-react-native-vector-icons-icons-you-dont-see

Comment: Works! Thanks. Small note: In place of gradle-7.6-all in the solution, check the precise version of gradle for your java sdk here in the [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) and find the exact name of the gradle zip file name at the [gradle distributions link](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was related to the fact that I had incompatible versions of Java and Gradle running together.
Look at this [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) to ensure that your installed Java version matches the Gradle one.